# Help identifying piece - wheels on arched base

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I'm not familiar with this piece that showed up in an old bin of Legos from a second hand store.

The text of the copyright reads "2008 the LEGO group"

Is there anyone that can tell me a part number or set this might have come from?

[image: the piece sitting on a table][image: the copyright text on the piece]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is: Part # 48394base

Bricklink:

[Sports Promo Skateboard Base with Four Wheels from McDonald's Sports Set Number 7, Set 7921](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48394base#T=C)

Brickset

[Set 7921-1: Skateboarder, Grey Vest](https://brickset.com/sets/7921-1/Skateboarder-Grey-Vest)

[image]